# web page design 

Tags: jsp, html, tiles

These days I am building a web site,and I am crazing by the page design.

For example:
There is a page when can be spitted to two parts,the left and the right.

The left is some menus,and the right is the main content.

When user click one menu in the left,the content in the right should be changed accordingly.

However,not all the contents own the same structure,so how to do?

Suppose the menu are listed below:

```
My group
  product01
  product02
My information
  My post
  my reply
  modify my information.
```

So ,how to design?

Use the jsp:include / tiles ?

but no matter use whatever, I have to create so many jsp fragment?

What is the best practice these days?

Comment: Can you sketch out what you are trying to do?  Are you just looking to have some left-hand vertical navigation?

Comment: No,it is not static page,it have to connect with the server side,with different menu,the content should be changed accordingly,so how to make the content change accordingly? A simple way is create pages with the same number with the number of the menu,but this will cause the repeat codes,also I know I can create some pages according the different menu,then use the jsp:include,but is this a good idea?

Comment: I can't follow what you are looking for, and I suspect that since nobody has answered this, others can't either.  Can you show us an example?

Comment: Sorry for my English express. I just mean what is the best practice when building web application user interface? apache tiles? or other template framework?

Comment: This depends on what you are wanting to achieve.  I usually just build my own interface, custom for each application.  You could use a templating system if you wanted to, but it might be excessive for a simple web application.  Each web application is different, and has different needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first step you should take is to design the entire site in static HTML.  Build the page as it makes sense.

Once you have the static page built, you can then decide how to split it up.  You may decide it is better to use a template system, or just do everything manually.  If you are having trouble with this decision, it helps to have the static page built first as a reference.